# Proof Expected Value for Independent random variables with n possibilities

Tags: proof-writing, expected-value, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$.

But when is $E(X^{m-k}Y^k)=E(X^{m-k})E(Y^k)$  true?
proof that ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent so are $X^{n}$ and $Y^{n}$.

Comment: You might want to read the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables).

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.